# AVD Emulators won't work

Tags: sdk, xamarin.android, android-emulator, hyper-v, android-virtual-device

I have Intel i5 2.39GHz 4GB 64bit windows 8.1 and can't get any Emulators to work. I tried the Xamarin with Visual Studio. The Emulator would appear for a second and never get it back.  Then I tried the Android Studio, this time the Emulator appears but can't get it to read my Hello World program and it gives error messages. Then I tried Eclipse, and the link to download SDK appears to be no longer working, so I can't even get Eclipse to show the Android as an option for project. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this might help someone, don't ask me why but I either accidentally or on purpose deleted all the emulators. Then I reinstalled them and BANG, everything works. It runs quiet fast I'd say. Possibly; emulators got corrupted? Not sure, but worth reinstalling, in my case anyway! The important part is that the software products I used to test Hyper-v and SLAT did not provide correct answers-obviously- because everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Running an Android emulator on a 4 GB system would be challenging. But try these and see if they work :

1. HAMX Hardware Acceleration for the Android Emulator (Search for this, not able to post link here)
2. Visual Studio Emulator for Android (this is old, but still good) : https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/
3. Genymotion : https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out these pages for tips on how to setup the Android Emulator for a fast experience:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-windows
- https://medium.com/google-developers/setting-up-the-android-emulator-for-speed-37ccbc3c3e1c

If you are using HyperV, you need to turn it off in order to use the fast Android Emulator on Windows 8.1.

Also to note, Google provided Android Developer Tools are [deprecated for Eclipse](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

Comment: This is my take-home laptop and would love to see if I can get it work. But there is some strange behavior. For instance, the HAXM and other requirements are already loaded, but then just as a test when I try to update these, I get error messages. So the machine (Dell E5440) has no problem loading the HAXM but won't update it !! I tried to find somebody at Dell but gave up real quick. The other issue is all the tests I've done won't clearly show wether it has SLAT or not.

Comment: Again, the strange thing is that I've loaded items that can only be done if it has SLAT capability, but the SLAT test fails at somethings but not others !! And I'm going WHAT???? So I finally gave up and tried to attach my phone and no IDE reads my phone either !!!!!

Comment: Sorry, give me a minute as I've changed my system many times for each IDE and now need to go back to original states. I'll start with Android Studio. Thanks for help

Comment: I somehow had deleted all the emulators. So trying to create a new one, the message was to turn off hyper-v. I remembered that I turned it off before, so not sure why I got this message. I proceeded to turn it off again and It got the "system32' not recognized as an internal or external command". So I'm tracing the path to see if it even exists. But not sure if I sure just delete the hyper-v if I find it or what?

Comment: OK, I guess I have to turn it on and off each time I reboot. But then why is it that I get this error message ? I'm working on this and any help will be appreciated